# Java Selenium Query

Tags: html, selenium

```
<div id="my_menu" class="sdmenu" style="float: left">
<div class="collapsed">
<span>Lookup and Levy Management</span>
```

I want to click on Lookup and Levy Management. How to do it in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Lookup and Levy Management')]")).click();
```